# Change every substrings between two symbol in string

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

In my angular code I want to replace string between two symbol like below

> Hello "I am" software coordinator as "freelancer"

to

> Hello {I am} software coordinator as  {freelancer}

but couldnt write it.

```
OnizleGoruntu(param){
  //I want to write code here
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values between `""` don't have any `"`  then you can simply use this pattern

```
"([^"]*)"
```

- `"` - Match `"`
- `([^"]*)` - Match anything except `"` zero or one time

```js
let str = `Hello "I am" software coordinator as "freelancer"`
let replaced = str.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, '{$1}')

console.log(replaced)
```

If there can `"` between `""` then you can try this

```
"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"
```

- `"` - Match `"`
- `((?:\\"|[^"]*))` - Match `\\"` or anything except `"` zero or more time

```js
let str = `Hello "I am" software coordinator as "freelancer" some more text "hello \\" hello"`
let replaced = str.replace(/"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"/g,'{$1}')

console.log(replaced)
```